# jQuery datepicker not working after ajax update on MVC partial view in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have an MVC view that has a div container which I update via ajax.

```
<div id="PartialContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        url: '/my/partial_action',
        success: function(result) {
            $("#PartialContainer").html(result);
        }
    });

</script>
```

The controller action code:

```
public ActionResult partial_action()
{
    return PartialView("_MyPartial");
}
```

And finally, _MyPartial view:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert("before");
        $("input.datepicker").datepicker();
        alert("after");
    });
</script>
```

The problem:
This works fine in Chrome, I get the datepicker dropdown fine, both alerts (before and after) show. In FF and IE however, the datepicker isn't working. I do get both alerts, but not the datepicker behavior. There are no firebug/F12 script errors.

I tried adding a datepicker input outside the partial view, and it worked fine in all browsers.

I'm using jQuery ui 1.7.2, mvc 4.

Anyone has any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:** So I solved the problem, it wasn't a javascript issue, but styling issue. I use the datepickers in a twitter bootstrap dialog, and it was covering the datepicker. Changing some z-indexed fixed it for me.

Comment: I've now checked it and it works as expected for me in FF 13, IE 9, Opera 12 and Safari 5. However IE seems to cache the result and probably it is the problem. Try to add some random arg to your url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove $.ready call and replace it with IIFE, so you code will be like following:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        alert("before");
        $("input.datepicker").datepicker();
        alert("after");
    })();
</script>
```

**EDIT:** I've now checked it and both cases work as expected for me in FF 13, IE 9, Opera 12 and Safari 5. However IE seems to cache the result and probably it is the problem. Try to add some random arg to your url or set `cache: false` (it is `true` by default) to ajax call in base page

```
<div id="PartialContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        url: '/my/partial_action',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#PartialContainer").html(result);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Didn't help. Same behavior in all browsers remains.

Comment: Cache off didn't help, too. Very weird case.

Comment: Do you have any "blocker"s plugins in FF and IE?

Comment: I solved it, it was styling issue with z-index and twitter bootstrap dialog. Big minus for me for not checking this earlier. I guess friday afternoons can do that to a person :)

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the similar behaviour with Bootstrap Datepicker v1.8.0. The datepicker worked as expected on the initial display of the partial view, but if the partial was refreshed with fresh data using an Ajax call the datepicker failed to respond.

By re-binding the text field to the datepicker in the Ajax success after the partialview was reloaded fixed the issue.

```
function editApplicant(id) {
var dataRow = {
    'applicant' : id
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Cases/GetApplicant",
    data: dataRow,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#applicantDetail').html(data);
        /* Rebind the date of birth field to a datepicker */
        $('#DOBString').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: 'bottom left'
        });
        showApplicantView();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        showApplicantView();
    }

});
```

}